# Prevent SQL Server restore function listing other user's databases

Tags: sql-server

I've setup a SQL Server and it has many databases from different users. I already setup each user to login to their own database and they won't see other people's database.

However, when a user goes to the SSMS restore database function, they can in the drop down list see all a list of all databases on the server.

1. What's the best way to prevent this?
2. Can we simply prevent users from using the restore function in SSMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to remove public permission to MSDB->backupfile and backupset tables.  OR deny certain users to those 2 tables.